# ASP.NET MVC 4 Wrong redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I have created a new action to confirm user account by a token sent in e-mail. It looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult ConfirmToken(string id)
    {
        bool isConfirmed;

        isConfirmed = WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(id);

        if (isConfirmed)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ConfirmSuccess });
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ConfirmFail });
        }
    }
```

And example link to this action would be: localhost:57904/Account/ConfirmToken/ubiJScfyP9zM1WUPCdb54Q2/

The problem is, I never ever get redirected to said Index action from Home controller. I constantly get redirected to Account/Login with previous link as a return URL in parameter. Doesn't matter what I add in the code.

- when I remove an entire ConfirmToken action, then I get an error
- when there is an action with nothing in its body, even then I am redirected to Account/Login

I am new to this ASP.NET MVC 4 concept, perhaps I am not doing something properly..? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

EDIT: I don't know if there's a problem with the code itself. It's an empty project I basically created a few hours ago and made minor modifications to the user registration process. It feels more like the code doesn't refresh since it DID contain redirection to Account/Login in the first place but then I wanted to change it.

EDIT2: Here's my Index/Home action

```
    public ActionResult Index(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.RegisterSuccess ? "An e-mail has been sent to the e-mail address you provided. It contains instructions how to confirm your account and finish the registration process. If you cannot see the e-mail in your inbox, please check spam folder."
            : message == ManageMessageId.ConfirmSuccess ? "Your account has been successfully confirmed and you can now login."
            : message == ManageMessageId.ConfirmFail ? "An error occured while activating your account. Please mail our support for assistance."
            : "";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Does Index/Home have an [Authorize] attribute on it? When you check your network requests, does it try to go to Home/Index or does it go direct to Account/Login

Comment: No, it doesn't have any attributes

Comment: are you using form authentication?

Comment: Yes, my Web.config says <authentication mode="Forms">.

Comment: What does your Index:Home action look like?

Comment: Added it to the first post

Comment: Shouldn't it be `message = ManageMessageId.ConfirmFail` in `ConfirmToken`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing an authentication issue try logging in before going confirming it will not redirect you the the login view.

If you decorated the class with `[Authorize]` then you need to allow all user on the controller action, otherwise it will keep redirecting you.

```
[Authorize]
public class ConfirmController : Controller {

  [AllowAnonymous]  
  public ActionResult ConfirmToken(string id)
  {
   //..
  }

}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had no idea this could be the cause!

Comment: I like how the first comment asked about an [Authorize] attribute and he said no.